# How to break find duplicate SQL query on a large table in multiple parts

Tags: mysql

I have a large table with ~3 million records in a MySQL database. I am trying to find duplicate rows in this table using the following query -

```
SELECT package_id
FROM version
WHERE metadata IS NOT NULL AND metadata <> '{}'
GROUP BY package_id, metadata HAVING COUNT(package_id) > 1
```

This query takes ~23 seconds to run on the database. Our database host however kill any query taking larger than 3 seconds using pt-kill. So I need to find a way to break this query down, such as each of the subpart would be a separate query and each one takes less than 3 seconds. Adding just a LIMIT constraint doesn't do it for the query, so how do I break a query to work on different parts of the table.

Result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE version`

```
  CREATE TABLE `version` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `package_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `version_number` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `current_state_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `md5sum` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cs NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uri` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cs NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `filename` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cs NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `size` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `metadata` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `storage_type_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_version_package_id_version_number` (`package_id`,`version_number`),
  KEY `idx_version_md5sum` (`md5sum`),
  KEY `idx_version_metadata` (`metadata`(255)),
  KEY `idx_version_current_state_id` (`current_state_id`),
  KEY `storage_type_id` (`storage_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `_fk_version_current_state_id` FOREIGN KEY (`current_state_id`) REFERENCES `state` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `_fk_version_package_id` FOREIGN KEY (`package_id`) REFERENCES `package` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3248761 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As can be seen there are many indexes on the table including index on Package_id + Version_number combination of field. The problem is that this table is only going to get bigger and I don't think Optimization even if it pulls me back in 3 second range would scale. So I need a way where I can partition this table and run on queries on separate parts.

Comment: Pls post the explain for the query and list the indexes in the version table, and perhaps describe how the data looks like in your table. Note: with that number of records you may want to switch hosting providers if the current one kills all queries over 3 secs.

Comment: Can you add an index to "package_id"? It should be very fast then.

Comment: Post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE version`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I've added the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE version` in the question.

Comment: How many distinct package-ids are there? `select count(distinct package_id)`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel there are 173645 distinct package_ids

Comment: Try to: Change `KEY idx_version_metadata (metadata(255))` to `KEY idx_version_metadata (metadata(255), package_id)` or create a new key. And change your GROUP BY clause to `GROUP BY metadata, package_id`. This will probably not help :-). Then try index `(package_id, metadata(255))` and your original query. That might work.

Comment: Also `metadata IS NOT NULL` is redundant because `metadata <> '{}'` will "fail" if `metadata` is null.

Comment: There are lots of things that can be done to fix this but none of it can be done in under 3 seconds. You really need to find yourself a decent hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to improve speed.

1. Create Table version_small with just columns id and package_id with index on package_id.
2. insert into version_small select id and package_id from version;
3. Run your original query on optimised table above - should be much faster on smaller table.

OR

1. Create Table version_small with just columns id and package_id, and a int counter with unique index on package_id.
2. insert into version_small select id and package_id from version, on duplicate key increment counter;
3. The rows with counter>1 are package_id that have more than one entry.